# Error using shapley for linear regression: TypeError: 'Lasso' object is not callable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

I'm using shap library to compare several models, one of those is a regularized linear regression, but when I try to create the explainer:

```
 shap.KernelExplainer(linear_reg,X1)
```

I get the following error:

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\common.py in match_model_to_data(model, data)
     87             out_val = model.f(data.convert_to_df())
     88         else:
---> 89             out_val = model.f(data.data)
     90     except:
     91         print("Provided model function fails when applied to the provided data set.")

TypeError: 'Lasso' object is not callable
```

Bellow is the code to reproduce this error:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression¿
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import shap
from sklearn import linear_model


X1,y1= make_regression(10,100)
linear_reg = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
linear_reg.fit(X1, y1)

shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(linear_reg,X1)
```

Comment: You are clearly following the shap documentation when passing the parameters. Maybe the problem is in the data shape(?)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have better results with:

```
explainer=shap.Explainer(linear_reg,X1)
shap_values=explainer(X1)
```